# Public & Private Keys in .NET besides RSA

Tags: .net, encryption, private-key, public-key-encryption

Am I missing something obvious here (I  hope I am), besides RSA, are there any other crypto methods in .NET that use a public & private key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rsa is derived from the class [AsymmetricAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.asymmetricalgorithm.aspx)

From there, MSDN lists the following derived classes:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.DSA
System.Security.Cryptography.ECDiffieHellman
System.Security.Cryptography.ECDsa
System.Security.Cryptography.RSA
```

Answer (score 0):

- [DSA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dsacryptoserviceprovider%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)
- [ECDiffieHelman](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng.aspx)  (Contrary to MSDN docs, *not* supported on Windows XP)

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography#Examples

Answer (score 0):

No. You are not missing anything. RSA appears to be the only public key encryption scheme implemented in .NET. DSA and ECDSA are signature schemes and Diffie-Hellman is a key agreement scheme.